# 3D interpolating

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d, interpolation, modelling

Our final year project domain is soil contamination modeling.  We collected soil samples at the depths of 0.3 cm ,0.5cm , 1cm , 1.5 cm in about 25 locations. We considered 8 contaminants- p h, sodium, magnesium, bicarbonates etc..  we have horizontally interpolated layers (As shape files) for all these contaminants. We like to produce a 3 D model of this situation which can yield us the extent of contamination for which we used "v. vol. rst module" of GRASS GIS.  The results were not acceptable. Should we try some other methodology or some other software to achieve vertical interpolation ?

Comment: In what way, precisely, were the results "not acceptable"? You should be prepared for visually poor interpolations unless your soil samples are *extremely* close to one another, because chemistry data for contaminated soils are notoriously variable, skewed, and subject to statistical censoring (from the nondetects). Have you done 2D and 3D visualizations of the *raw data* to evaluate your prospects?

Comment: Please edit your post and explain what "horizontally interpolated layers (As shape files)" means - usually interpolated layers are raster maps...